# Uploading image to server reached damaged using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, http, afnetworking

Ive been trying so hard to upload an Image to the server and it uploads successfully but on the server side if i tried opening the image it says `cannot be displayed because it contains errors`.I am using AFNetworking to upload the image after converting it to JPEGRepresentation.

```
let uploadManager : AFHTTPSessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

        uploadManager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer() as AFHTTPResponseSerializer
        uploadManager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer() as AFHTTPRequestSerializer

        uploadManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 20

        uploadManager.POST(baseURL, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData) -> Void in

            let selectedImage = self.userImage.image
            let imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage!, 0.5)!
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "1", fileName: "userimage\(self.objManager.userID)", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            print("Size of Image(Kbytes):\(imageData.length/1024)")
            print(baseURL)
            }, progress: nil, success: { (task, responseObject) -> Void in

                let jsonData: NSData = responseObject as! NSData
                let dataString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)

            }) { (task, error) -> Void in


        }
```

The image comes from `imagePickerController`:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    print("Did finish picking the image succesfully")
    self.userImage.image = image
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    // call uploading image function


}
```

What is causing the image to be damaged ? I've been in contact with backend developer and his mechanism is to receive byte array ! sending NSData to the server and then the server convert my NSData to byte array is damaging the image ? or its ok ? How do i fix this issue ? is there is anything wrong I'm doing when i am sending the image ?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In `(task, error) -> Void in` print error if it exists, because if something goes wrong you receive error there.

```
NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
```

**2)** Are you sure that `name: "1"` is write? Because this is the name of field where the backend get the file data (ask about this field name your backend developer)

**3)** Append file type `jpeg` to uploading image name:

```
formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "1", fileName: "userimage\(self.objManager.userID).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

Comment: The images gets to the server and stored there in the success block and there is no error.Also i tried note 3 but still the image has the same error. i will check note 2 and i will let you know ! :) Thanks